# javascript how to find that DOM node that contains a text?

Tags: javascript, dom, html-parsing, domparser

Given a fetched html page, I want to find the specific node that contains a portion of text. The hard way I guess it would be to iterate to all the nodes one by one, getting as deep as it goes, and for each case do a search with e.g. `.includes()`

But how is the wise way? There must be something, but I'm unable to google correctly for it

```
    response = axios.get(url);
    let parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(response.data, 'text/html');
    for (let i = 0; i < parsedHtml.children.length; i++)
       if (parsedHtml.children[i].textContent.includes('hello'))
          console.log(parsedHtml.children[i])
```

*it doesn't work

*Example code

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div>dfsdf</div>
  <div>
   <div>dfsdf</div>
   <div>dfsdf</div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <div>hello</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div>dfsdf</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I would like to retrieve `<div>hello</div>` as a node element

Comment: Related: [Finding the DOM element with specific text and modify it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132074/finding-the-dom-element-with-specific-text-and-modify-it).

Comment: Thanks! you link has driven me to other links that finally ended up with this solution I've just posted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting almost convinced that I had to traverse the DOM the classical way, I've found this here [Javascript: How to loop through ALL DOM elements on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256339/javascript-how-to-loop-through-all-dom-elements-on-a-page) which is indeed excellent:

```
    let nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
        parsedHtml,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
        (node) => {
            return (node.textContent.includes('mytext1')
                || node.textContent.includes('mytext2'))
                && node.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'script' // not interested in the script
                && node.children.length === 0 // this is the last node
                ? NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
        }
    );
    let pars = [];
    let currentNode;

    while (currentNode = nodeIterator.nextNode())
        pars.push(currentNode);
    console.log(pars[0].textContent); // for example
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using jQuery

You can use [**jQuery's `:contains()` selector**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) like this:

```
$(":contains('hello')")
```

[**Demo in CodePen**](https://codepen.io/KyleMit/pen/rNRGbMr)

Just be aware that this will also count any parent nodes that also happen to contain the same text.  If your DOM structure allows it would be good to target the *type* of node you're looking for (i.e. class selector) and then check if that type of element contains the text you're looking for.

#### Using Vanilla JS

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("div")]
  .filter(el => el.textContent.includes("hello"))
```

[**Demo in Codepen**](https://codepen.io/KyleMit/pen/gOEGVGM?editors=1111)

#### <del>CSS</del>

There was a consideredation for [`:contains` in CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#content-selectors) as a Content Selector in CSS 3, but it was abandoned.

#### Further Reading

- [Finding the DOM element with specific text and modify it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6132074/1366033)
- [How to find a DOM element by its text content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58052522/1366033)
- [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1520429/1366033)